# how to display an inverted image on the screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

please help display the inverted image on screen("main"-window).

```
import os, sys
import tkinter
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage, Image

main = tkinter.Tk()


catalog1 = 'imgs'
catalog2 = 'newImgs'
file1 = 'n.jpg'
ima1 = os.path.join(catalog1, file1)

objImg = Image.open(ima1)
rotImg = objImg.rotate(270)

#renderImg = PhotoImage(file=ima1)
#tkinter.Label(main, image=renderImg).pack()


rotImg.save(catalog2 + '/' + 'cv.jpg')

main.mainloop()
```

I did it only to withdraw in an inverted image file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this code **(updated )** :

```
import os, sys
import Tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

main = Tkinter.Tk()

catalog1 = 'imgs'
catalog2 = 'newImgs'
file1 = 'n.png'
ima1 = os.path.join(catalog1, file1)
img_path = "%s/%s"%(catalog1,file1);
image_ob = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_path).rotate(270))
Tkinter.Label(main,text="",image=image_ob).pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: but your the image is not inverted :)
270 degree

Comment: Ops , didn't notice the retation thing ,sorry , i ll try something

Answer (score 1):

From your example, you could just reuse your label code with this renderImg

```
renderImg = PhotoImage(image=rotImg)
```

`PhotoImage` is an *Tkinter compliant image* class that you can build from either

- **image=** PIL Image
- **file=** file
- **data=** raw data (usually binary image content in a string)